# Aws EC2 EBS setup gives error ls: cannot open directory /mnt/my-data/: permission denied

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am learning amazon EC2 using the EC2 user guide document. My aim is to attach an EBS volume to a running EC2 instance. I have already done this successfully. However I now want to mount it after connecting through the SSH from my linux machine. I have successfully done the steps provided in the manual:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/my-data 
sudo mount /dev/sdf /mnt/my-data
```

(however in my case the sudo mount /dev/sdf1 /mnt/my-data worked instead)

But I can't view the contents using `ls /mnt/my-data` (which is also provided as step in the user guide).

Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: the fact that the latter command worked is because you mount a partition, not the whole disk. Now, you need to confirm if that partition is formatted / initialized as filesystem (say, ext3, ext4, etc). After that then you can mount it. If you'll be using this partition often then the recommended practice is to add the partition to `/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you create /mnt/my-data using the above two commands, the directory ends up being owned by root. In order to change this:

```
sudo chown -R ec2-user:ec2-user /mnt/my-data
```

(Assuming ec2-user is your current user.)

Now it should work and you should be able to use that directory as your regular user.

Comment: This solved my problem but as I'm working with a Ubuntu instance the syntax was 
sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /mnt/my-data

Answer (score 0):

Or, here's another syntax example:

get filesystem info:

ubuntu@ip-10-29-192-104:/mnt$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      7.9G  883M  6.7G  12% /
udev            819M   12K  819M   1% /dev
tmpfs           331M  172K  331M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            827M     0  827M   0% /run/shm
/dev/xvdb       147G  188M  140G   1% /mnt

In this case, the new EBS is mounted on /mnt
This is an Ubuntu image, so the username is ubuntu.

sudo chown -R ubuntu:ubuntu /mnt/

Now the /mnt is owned by "ubuntu" not "root"